# What would be the correct code in order to get the factorial of n?

Tags: python, numbers, factorial

n=int(input("Enter a number: ")) p=1 for i in range(n): p*=i
print(p)

I wanted to find out the factorial of a number but I always get 0 as output

Answer (score 0):

range(x) is from 0 by default to x-1, so e.g. range(3) is 0, 1, 2

You want to start from 1 and go to x+1 probably:

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
factorial = 1
for i in range(1,n+1):
    factorial*=i
    print(factorial)
```